# invalid result in mysql selector via python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I want to select a row in mysql table via 3 conditions but when i run the code the selector conditions not work correctly , is there any limit for number of conditions for mysql selectors? 
in this case when i run the following code the result is correct, it show the rows who inserted in last 90 min and the post_id is not null  :

```
import mysql.connector

lucas_db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user="root",
    password="zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
    database="Lucas_database")


mycursor_tv = lucas_db.cursor()
mycursor_tv.execute(
    "SELECT Release_Name FROM Lucas_t_db WHERE Published_Time > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIME, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) AND Post_ID IS NOT NULL")
myresult_tv = mycursor_tv.fetchall()
print(">>>> Last 30 Minute Release: ", len(myresult_tv))
myresult_tv = [a[0] for a in myresult_tv]

print(myresult_tv)
```

but when i change the selector like following codes the `post_id is not null` condition  dose not work :

```
"SELECT Release_Name FROM Lucas_t_db WHERE Published_Time > SUBDATE( CURRENT_TIME, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) AND Post_ID IS NOT NULL AND Post_status IS NULL
```

i just add `AND Post_status IS NULL` after `Post_ID IS NOT NULL` and make every thing wrong. it should show the rows who inserted last 90 min and post id  is not null and post status is null 
(sorry for my bad English grammar :))

Comment: Did you mean to leave off the trailing `")` from the query string in the second code block?

Comment: Does the query throw an error?  Or does it not show the results you need?